# ui.bootstrap.datepicker : change date format

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to custom the ui.bootstrap.datepicker there http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

I would like to set the format to dd-MM-yy and make it work with the input with the mask (the second one below 'Popup' in the plunkr)

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
```

I have added a new format in script.js :

```
  $scope.formats = ['dd-MM-yy', 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
```

Is there a way to change the format of the second datepicker (under 'Popup'), the one with `<input type="date"...>` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 date input types do not support custom formats. See [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) for more information. I think it is better to change input type to text, like the first one.

Comment: if I do that, only the first datepicker (under 'Popup') has its format changed  http://plnkr.co/edit/dGWvB5bHvpeQdGnJQKf2?p=preview

Comment: You asked you want to change format of datepicker of input. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: it's ok, I have managed to do what I wanted : allow user to type the date manually with the format dd-MM-yy (http://plnkr.co/edit/fTFNu9Mp2kX5X1D6AJOx?p=preview)